Jetpack compose, navigate to screen with new backstack
Let's say I have a backstack as: ScreenA, ScreenB, ScreenC.
Now on ScreenC i have a button that should navigate to ScreenF. But it also should remove the current backstack. So the result i want is backstack that looks like this:
ScreenD, ScreenE, ScreenF.
Is it possible?
It's really easy to do it with Voyager, but lately Voyager is not being updated so I may be forced to implement standart google library :(
